# Issue with system() call when cross compiling for Android

Tags: android, cross-compiling

Based on some limitations with the NDK standalone toolchain and bionic, I have rolled my own toolchain using crosstool-NG with these general settings:

- binutils-2.22
- gcc-4.5.3 with gfortran enabled
- glibc-2.14.1
- kernel-headers-2.35.7
- arch arm4t

Using this I build an executable and upload all dependencies, including libc, ld-linux etc with it onto my Android device.  I manually run the executable with ld-linux.so.3 --library-path ...

It is a very complex executable, and it all seems to work except, if I do any system() call, even something basic, like system("pwd") or system(NULL) I get 127 as the status (not found).  If I go further and use popen instead to collect a response, I get:

***glibc detected *** double free or corruption

What is going on?  Has anyone succeeded at doing similar?  Is there a permissions issue?  Is there something fundamentally different about Android that makes system() calls not possible?  Where can I find out how bionic handles system and popen (source code) in the end, because I think if you use the NDK you can do system() calls.

Comment: When do you get the glibc error? On the `popen` call? Or on some call after that?

Comment: `/bin/sh` isn't on Android; it's in `/system/bin/sh` AFAIK. glibc most likely just uses `/bin/sh`.

Comment: nneonneo-Do you know where the system() calls are handled in glibc?  Specifically, where in the source code?  Other than modifying the source code, is there some better way to override where it would look, like and environment variable?

Comment: David Schwartz-I believe it is on the popen call.  I stepped through it before, but I will double check.

Comment: `system` is in `sysdeps/posix/system.c`; popen *was* in `libio/oldiopopen.c` back in glibc-2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) `SHELL` environment variable is unlikely to be set on Android. The default shell `/bin/sh` doesn't exist (AFAIK); it's in `/system/bin/sh`. This is likely what causes `system` to fail.

(2) You can find the implementations on GitHub: [system](https://github.com/android/platform_bionic/blob/master/libc/unistd/system.c), [popen](https://github.com/android/platform_bionic/blob/master/libc/unistd/popen.c). Your crash in glibc sounds like a library bug to me (unless you're using `popen` from a signal handler or in a multithreaded environment)

Comment: SHELL was not set, but setting it didn't solve my issue, by itself.  Need to go back to a simpler test case and then will report back.  I think with what you and David have suggested, I will probably have a path forward, but need to understand the issue better first.

Comment: Well, it turns out `system` uses `#define SHELL_PATH "/bin/sh"`. So much for affecting it through `SHELL`...

Comment: modifying the glibc source code to define the shell path correctly has the system call working, but making the same change for popen did not fix the issues.  digging in further into that now.

Comment: I fooled myself it did work for popen once I modified the correct files.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest just rolling your own version of `system`. It's not complicated at all and that will enable you to determine the exact system call that failed and what error it fails with. Most likely, the shell isn't correct and that's what's generating the error -- your library is specifying a shell program that doesn't exist.